# Issue with string creation C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want to make a function that create a new string with a specific lenght.
This is the code:

```
char* newString(int lenght){

    char* newstring =(char*)((calloc(lenght, sizeof(char))));
    newstring[lenght] = '\0';
    return newstring;
}
```

I use it in this way:

```
char* string = newString(10);
```

My problem is that when I do:

```
printf("String lenght  %lu \n",strlen(string));
```

I get 0 but I don't understand why.
I am neophyte with C.
Thank for your time

Comment: Because `calloc` zero initializes your array, and you never populate it with anything. Also, it's spelled "length"

Comment: ...and you're exceeding your allocated length with `t[lenght] = '\0'` regardless, thus invoking undefined behavior. Arrays in C are zero-base-indexed. Meaning `0...(lenght-1)` are the allowable range of indexes..

Comment: `t[length] = '\0';` is an out of bound write.

Comment: I do : newstring[lenght-1]='\0' but the problem remains

Answer (score 4):

`strlen` returns the number of characters before the first `'\0'`. You'll get the same result if you use:

```
char s[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int len = strlen(s); // len will be zero.
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of issues here. The first is that you're terminating t (and I'm not sure what t references actually) with a null-terminator at index "length", which will be one greater than the size of the array. So you're accessing some random blob of memory there. The second is improperly using calloc. I think you want something more like:

```
char* new_string(int length) {
    char* new_string;
    new_string = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
    memset(new_string, 0, length);
    new_string[length-1] = '\0';
    return new_string;
}
```

Strlen in your example returns 0 because it counts the characters before the null terminator, which happens to be 0 in your implementation.

Comment: OP's use of `calloc` is correct. You do the same exact thing, just with more lines of code. Technically, all this function has to do is `return calloc(length, sizeof(char));`

Comment: I know that the calloc function resets memory(in addition to allocate memory), the function memset does the same thing? what change?

Answer (score 0):

If length doesn't include the null termination then you should set t[length - 1] to zero, or alternatively calloc with size length + 1.

Comment: If posting an answer, maybe consider answering the question question posted: why `strlen(string)` reports `0`.

Answer (score 0):

strlen count the number of character in the c string until it see a "\0" (end of string) so as your string is initialized with "\0" its length is actually 0. change this value to another one like.

```
  memcpy(string, "good things", 10);
  printf("%d", strlen(string));
```